# Golang nested struct slice - Error index out of range

Tags: arrays, go, struct, slice

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lCz0EnnREKp)

I'm trying to store a string into a slice field inside a struct. This is for collecting data and create a Json to post via to an API.

```
package main

type response1 struct {
Identifier string `json:"identifier"`
Family     string `json:"family"`
Values     struct {
    Logo []struct {
        Data string `json:"data"`
        Scope string `json:"scope"`
    } `json:"logo"`
  }
}

func main() {

    res2D := &response1{
        Identifier: "1234567",
        Family:     "example",
    }

    res2D.Values.Logo[0].Data = "test"

    res2B, _ := json.Marshal(res2D)

    fmt.Println(string(res2B))
}
```

**Error**

And the error I got:

```
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox507443306/main.go:22 +0xe0
```

Comment: You must `make` the slice with appropriate size before you can assig to it elements. Take the Tour of Go.

Comment: You do not have to make the slice with appropriate size before hand.  Look at my answer for details.

Comment: go lang is a `static type language` if you are using an array means you need to use `make` to fix the size of an `array`

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to `make` the slice with appropriate size before hand.  You can use append.  What you are trying to do in your example is assign a slice "[0]" that has not been created yet, which is why you are getting your error.  Use append and change your line

```
res2D.Values.Logo[0].Data = "test"
```

to

```
res2D.Values.Logo = append(res2D.Values.Logo,struct {Data string "json:\"data\"" }{Data: "test"})
```

and that will append the literal struct into your array.  Now by looking at your code I am assuming you doing this as a test to explore the language so I wont go into detail on how to better write this without knowing what you are actually using it for.

Comment: Thank you Dan! You are absolut right. To less information! I added more Informations. Your solution works fine with but not when the Slice has more then one childs. Then it failed again. Next time I will directly add more Informations :-)

Comment: No, why, Dan's code fill be fine. It will just append your substruct to the slice.